# how to make run sql query fast the following query keep on running suggest me how to optimize it

Tags: sql, oracle10g

/* Formatted on 2015/06/24 15:51 (Formatter Plus v4.8.5) */

```
SELECT   (SELECT NAME
            FROM dept
           WHERE deptid = department) AS NAME, SUM (received),
         SUM (notresponded)
    FROM (SELECT     TRIM (regexp_substr (b.dept, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                          ) AS department,
                     COUNT (*) received,
                       COUNT (*)
                     - COUNT
                          (CASE
                              WHEN ROUND
                                     (  (  TO_DATE
                                               (TO_CHAR (clssndtm,
                                                         'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                        ),
                                                'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                               )
                                         - TO_DATE
                                               (TO_CHAR (made,
                                                         'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                        ),
                                                'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                               )
                                        )
                                      * 24
                                     ) <= 1
                                 THEN ROUND
                                        (  (  TO_DATE
                                                 (TO_CHAR
                                                         (clssndtm,
                                                          'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                         ),
                                                  'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                 )
                                            - TO_DATE
                                                 (TO_CHAR
                                                         (made,
                                                          'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                         ),
                                                  'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'
                                                 )
                                           )
                                         * 24
                                        )
                              ELSE NULL
                           END
                          ) notresponded
                FROM reportng a, routing b
               WHERE a.ticket = b.ticket
                 AND (1 = 1)
                 AND a.rptflag = 1
                 AND a.clssndtm IS NOT NULL
                 AND companyid = 2682
          CONNECT BY INSTR (dept, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
                 AND TRUNC (made) BETWEEN TRUNC (TO_DATE ('06/01/2015',
                                                          'mm/dd/yyyy'
                                                         )
                                                )
                                      AND TRUNC (TO_DATE ('06/23/2015',
                                                          'mm/dd/yyyy'
                                                         )
                                                )
            GROUP BY TRIM (regexp_substr (dept, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)))
GROUP BY department
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want the query to be readable, otherwise it's impossible to see what's going on:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT NAME FROM dept WHERE deptid = department) AS NAME,
    SUM (received),
    SUM (notresponded)
FROM
    (SELECT
        TRIM (regexp_substr (b.dept, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) ) AS department,
        COUNT () received,
        COUNT () - COUNT (CASE WHEN ROUND ( ( TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (clssndtm, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ) - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (made, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ) ) * 24 ) <= 1 THEN ROUND ( ( TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (clssndtm, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ) - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (made, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi' ) ) * 24 ) ELSE NULL END ) notresponded
    FROM
        reportng a,
        routing b
    WHERE
        a.ticket = b.ticket
        AND (1 = 1)
        AND a.rptflag = 1
        AND a.clssndtm IS NOT NULL
        AND companyid = 2682
        CONNECT BY INSTR (dept, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0 AND TRUNC (made) BETWEEN TRUNC (TO_DATE ('06/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) ) AND TRUNC (TO_DATE ('06/23/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) )
    GROUP BY
        TRIM (regexp_substr (dept, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
    )
GROUP BY
    department
```

Now, there's some Oracle specific stuff in there that I don't understand but we can see there's 2 different major steps here. There's the first inner query, that may or may not be running efficiently. Run that on its own to see how it goes. I'm going to assume it's fine (it may not be).

The outer bit is definitely going to be suboptimal as you have a correlated query in the SELECT clause. That needs to be split out into a join:

```
SELECT
    dept.NAME,
    SUM (received),
    SUM (notresponded)
FROM
    complex_inner_query
    inner join dept on dept.deptid = complex_inner_query.department
GROUP BY
    department
```

That may well solve your problems, but if not you need to start analyzing the inner query to find the inefficiency.